# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'profiles_category' already exists")

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to host my website using FileZilla and PuTTY. For that, I have added the code in FileZilla remote site and I have created a database named jobs using following commands in PuTTY app.

```
sudo mysql -u root #For Maria DB
CREATE DATABASE jobs;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON jobs.*TO 'hello'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
exit
```

Then `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command is executed and after that when I executed the `python3 manage.py migrate` command I got an error like this.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'profiles_category' already exists")
```

Here the table `profiles_category` is not already existed.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class CategoryJob(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

just delete db.sqlite.sql file,

delete also: all migrations and cache

THEN

```
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py makemigrations
```

finally :

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

I had / have a similar problem - if you that it might work for you also.